# Cannot read Custom Attributes

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I have a problem to read a Custom Attributes.
I have read more tutorial for this, but cannot read the value.

NB: I use a console application.

Main Class

```
namespace IRCBotter
{
    public class IrcBot
    {
        [UserLevel(LevelRequired = 10)]
        void HelpCommand(string user)
        {
            GetAttribute(typeof(IrcBot));
        }

        public static void GetAttribute(Type t)
        {
            // Get instance of the attribute.
            UserLevel MyAttribute =
                   (UserLevel)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(UserLevel));

               if (MyAttribute == null)
               {
                   Message.Error("The attribute was not found.");
               }
               else
               {
                   // Get the Name value.
                   Message.Error("Valore " + MyAttribute.LevelRequired.ToString());
               }
           }
     }
}
```

Attribute Class

```
namespace IRCBotter.Commands
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All ,AllowMultiple=true)]
    class UserLevel : Attribute
    {
        public int LevelRequired { get; set; }
    }
}
```

on debug, Console say me "The attribute was not found".
Have a one simple working example for get correct value from custom attribute?

In the `void HelpCommand`
need to check if variable user stored is equal in one stored list
and him level is > in LevelRequired.

Comment: First you missing public access modifier on your attribute before class.
At which line you get the exception?

Comment: no, nothing. but value is null

Comment: Do yourself and follow the naming conventions for attributes.  Your class should be named `UserLevelAttribute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared the attribute on the class, you defined it on the method `HelpCommand`. You will have to get the `MethodInfo` for `HelpCommand` and call `GetCustomAttribute` on that. Something along these lines.

```
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("HelpCommand");
UserLevel userLevel = method.GetCustomAttribute<UserLevel>();
```

Comment: i try tanks daniel

Comment: Fixed tanks daniel but one fix at your code, for me   GetCustomAttribute<UserLevel>();  does work. Just simple edited in object[] userLevel = method.GetCustomAttribute(false);